# WP preg_match and REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a very small wordpress plugin but I seem to be having issues on using it. The **add_action('template_redirect', 'example_function');** works as it should be and the function is called correctly.

The line that is not working is: **if(preg_match('#^/api/(.*)$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)) {** The /api/ part and the ^/ are wrong.

Can somebody help me fixing my line? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe remove the `^` so it isn't trying to find `/api/` at the beginning or the URL, since may sites use `/wordpress/` as their root directory?  What exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
(this will only work if the file runs from the top directory of your domain)

if your path is inside another dir (like: http://www.mydomain.com/dir/api/bla.php) remove the `^` from the beginning of the pattern

```
if(preg_match('/^\/?api\/(.*)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $match)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was helpful.